# running .NET in sles 11

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core

i'm trying to figure out if it is possible to run .NET on the server at work. we mainly run COBOL but i want to know if it is possible to run .NET also.
this is what i can find that is installed on the server:

```
cobol v5.1.00
PRN=RXCVF/AAP:9t.r3.51.13
PTI=WrapPack 12
PTI=SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
PTI=ES

LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Release:        11
Codename:       n/a
```

i don't think i'm allowed to give much more info than this. i hope this can give me something that i know what i can do to make .net run.

regards,

bjorn

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mono. It isn't a perfect clone of .Net, and Windows apps might not work perfectly on it. For example, it does not support WPF. However, it does have basic functionality.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)#Current_status_and_roadmap